# FeignException$Unauthorized: [401 ] during [POST] не выполняется запрос на получение токена через Feign

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

```
@FeignClient(name = "ApiClient", url = "${api.url}")
public interface FeignApiClient {
    @PostMapping(
            value = {"/login"},
            consumes = {APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" )
    LoginResponse getToken(@RequestBody LoginRequest request);
}
```

---

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

---

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class XAuthRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if(requestAttributes != null){
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
            String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            template.header("Authorization", authorization);

        }
    }
}
```

ошибка:

```
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401 ] during [POST] to [https://auth.api.ru/api/v1/login] [FeignAuthCustodySecuritiesClient#getToken(LoginRequest)]: []
```

адрес куда я обращаюсь для логина и получения токена. так работает сторонний сервис - параметры передаются

```
POST https://auth.api.ru/api/v1/login
{ "username": "user", "password": "pwd" }
```

при выполнении через Postman токен приходит.
креды передаются в теле post запроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]